# How to find downloaded .apk files on my Android phone

Tags: applications, google-play-games

I usually download apps and games from Google Play but I wonder if i could reuse these files and find them again if my application has been removed?
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have root permissions and are open to use scripts, you may want to use mine: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/143449/152843

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of [apps to backup the `.apk`](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_132) file of apps from your device, making the process much easier than fiddling with file explorers. I e.g. used [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager) quite a while; its [paid version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think_android.appmanagerpro) even automatically captures the `.apk` of each app when it's installed or updated. Looks like the app is discontinued – but there are several similar apps you can find listed behind the first link.

Once you've got the `.apk`, you can of course side-load it to another device if needed. I've usually done that if I needed the same app on another device which didn't have Playstore access. Note that this doesn't always work with paid apps: if those use Google's license check, the "target device" needs to be setup with the same Google account the app was acquired, and of course needs the Playstore app and network access to verify the license.

Of course you can use the `.apk` to reinstall the app even if it was removed from Playstore. License check should work fine then as well (provided you've got the Playstore app and your account setup, as described in the previous paragraph).

Comment: I used [AppMonster v5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think_android.apps.appmonster.cloud.free) to save the discontinued [Beep n'go](http://beepngo.com/) apk, no root permission needed, brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Use any root-enabled file explorer and go to /data/app for your APK.

You need to know the package name of your app, but then again, most package names are closely related to the app name itself, so you should be able to find it easily.

If you don't have root access, then I don't have any suggestion for you, other than downloading the APK from sites like APKMirror and APKPure if it's a free app.

One last thing: if you're intending to commit piracy by ripping out the APK of a paid app, be aware that it is discouraged behavior and might land you troubles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to root your phone. User RootExplorer or any other app like that to view your apk.
Other wise there is no luck.